# Microsoft Education - School Data Sync (SDS) to Microsoft Graph Mapping

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

We are working with schools who use Microsoft Education and School Data Sync  (SDS) to load their teachers, students and groups. In SDS there are some properties such as Grade, GraduationYear etc. and we´ve been trying to figure out if these are accessible via the Microsoft Graph API.

With a bit of experimentation and [via this article](https://teams.rocks/2018/06/25/microsoft-365-automation-using-sds-attributes-intune-graph/), we can see on Groups and Users certain properties we can get prefixed with `extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_`. `fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3` seems to be the app id for SDS.

We were wondering if this is a sensible route to get at these properties from SDS or if there is a better route for getting these? We can, for example, see the `term` information available in [`classes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationclass?view=graph-rest-1.0) but we don´t see the subject information there.

For groups:

Groups: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{Id}?$select=extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_{Name}`

Note: Groups in SDS are called sections

- Status (e.g.`extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_Status`)
- Period - This seems to be called periods in the import files
- CourseSubject - e.g. History
- CourseDescription - e.g. History of the World
- CourseName
- CourseNumber
- TermEndDate
- TermStartDate
- TermName
- SyncSource_CourseId
- SyncSource_TermId
- SectionName - this is the name that comes from the SDS file

Users: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{Id}?select=$extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_{Name}`

- Grade
- GraduationYear
- SyncSource_StudentId
- ObjectType - Shows if this a teacher or a student
- DateOfBirth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only supported route to access this information is through the Education Graph APIs [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/education-concept-overview).  Right now that is a subset of the properties imported by School Data Sync.  The underlying extension properties should be considered a point-in-time implementation detail and not relied upon in production apps.

Current plan  as of Feb 2019 is to add the course information to the educationClass object in the next couple of months.  That just leaves a few properties different across the education entities which we don't have a concrete plan for yet.